# make motor ON and OFF for fixed interval of time

Tags: microcontroller, 555

I am new to electronic, studied this subject long time back but now not able to recall anything out of it. I have requirement to ON the motor after fix interval of 4 hours and run it for 30 seconds and turn it OFF, this cycle will repeat as long as power supply is maintained, I gone through some of the web links where they had explained the use of 555 and 4060B for this perpose, they also have suggestion to use microcontroller for this. I need cheapest possible solution for this.

I will be thankful if someone help me on this.

Comment: Get a small Microcontroller, 555 are not ideal for such long time periods.

Answer (score 3):

A <s>666</s> 555 timer is not appropriate here.  Such long times are best done digitally by dividing down a faster clock.

Even the cheap and tiny PIC 10F200 microcontroller can do this easily.  The circuit will be smaller and about the same cost as a 555 timer, but irrelevant anyway compared to the cost of the motor and the circuit to do the high power switching.  Both the 555 and microcontroller solution give you a digital signal indicating when the motor should be on, and require other circuitry to use that to actually switch the motor.

The 10F200 comes with a internal 1 MHz oscillator.  It also has a 8 bit timer, and that timer can be configured with a 8 bit prescaler.  I'd count overflows of that timer to do the timing.  (1 MHz)/65536 = 15.3 Hz, so there are 220 k overflows in 4 hours.  30 seconds is 458 overflows.

You only need three bytes of RAM as a counter.  Initialize these to 220 k, and decrement once every timer 1 overflow.  When it reaches 0, turn on the motor.  Set the counter to 458.  Decrement every timer 1 overflow.  When it reaches 0, turn off the motor and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Olin´s answer is perfect: forget 555's (we're in 2016).

I would like just to add that the non-electronic-skilled person would find easier to use an Arduino board, simplifying the wiring and the programming tasks. It wouldn't be necessary to build a PCB or even to solder anything. But that simplicity, as anything, has a price: the Arduino-based device would not be so reliable as a properly built (PCB, solder, etc) device...

A halfway solution could be an ATTiny microcontroler, that can be programmed with the Arduino IDE and an Arduino board as a programmer. For a task so simple like this, even the bloatest code should work fine.